# how to make an input that only allows numbers, backspace, and delete keys

Tags: javascript, html

I have this input

```
<input name="minSalary" value="49800" style="width: 45px" maxlength="5" id="numbersonly"></td>
```

and this script

```
document.getElementById('numbersonly').onkeydown = function(e) {
    var key = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which;
    if ( isNaN( String.fromCharCode(key) ) ) return false;
}
```

Right now the input only responds when numbers are pressed. I would also like to respond to backspace and delete.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can also allow the keycodes `8` (backspace) and `46` (delete) to achieve this

```
document.getElementById('numbersonly').onkeydown = function(e) {
    var key = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which;
    if ( isNaN( String.fromCharCode(key) ) && key != 8 && key != 46 ) return false;
}
```

Maybe you should also allow `37` and `39` for navigation with the arrow keys inside the input

Here is a list of all keycodes available: http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes